# Where do these version numbers come from "module-name-1.0-alpha1+13-dev" with plus?

Tags: community-official-site

I've started to work in an existing drupal development project and wanted to do some module updates and found modules with versions like this:

- Universally Unique IDentifier 7.x-1.0-alpha3+47-dev
- Taxonomy CSV import/export 7.x-5.10+17-dev

I've never seen this before. According to drupal [version number guidelines](http://drupal.org/node/467026) this is not wanted.

Now, our head developer says they *never* modified any contributed modules and only took them from drupal.org ... Where do that version numbers come from?

Did I miss something?

Comment: Last packaged version: 7.x-5.10+17-dev - http://drupal.org/node/882530 - this is a information added by drupal.org packaging script, do not worry ;)

Comment: ah, interesting. but my drupal installation recommends to install 7.x-5.10 instead of 7.x-5.10+17-dev ... ?

Comment: That's because using dev-versions in general is discouraged.

Comment: ok, got it. why is it not called 7.x-5.x-dev anymore?

Comment: @Letharion  -dev version are discouraged, except when the maintainers say to use them.  I am pretty sure -dev is the preferred version of UUID right now.

Comment: @MPD I'm well aware that -dev versions are discouraged, I strongly try to avoid them myself, but I found that to be out of scope for this whole discussion, so I decided to not open up that debate :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-dev versions, are regularly built from the latest source code.

To differentiate between todays -dev release, and yesterdays, the number you've indicated counts the number of changes between any two dev releases.

Comment: so basicly 7.x-5.10+17-dev is a more detailed version number of 7.x-5.x-dev?

Comment: Yes, it says '17 commits on -dev since the last release', in this case, 5.10.

Comment: alright, this is still a bit confusing in the "available updates" page. thanks for clarification!